# React, Too many rerenders

Tags: reactjs, rerender

Given the following code:

```
export default function CrearContacto({setOpening}) {
    
      const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
      setOpen(setOpening);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        console.log(setOpening);
        setOpen(setOpening);
      }, [setOpening]); 
    
      const handleClose = () =>{setOpening=false};
    
      return (
        <div>
          <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
//code continues
```

I'm getting a Too many re-renders error, however I'm unable so see where is the loop here. `{setOpening}` is being used in a button in another component, when clicked, `true` is sent. `setOpen` sets new open state as `true`, so `Dialog` can pop-up. At the same time `useEffect` is watching `setOpening` for changes (probably this is also wrong, I'm trying to make this work without success). If closed, `handleClose` is triggered and now `setOpening` equals `false`, so `useEffect` detects the change and executes `setOpen` to `false`. I don't see the loop, but also the code isn't working as intended.

Edit - Added parent relative code

```
function Agenda() {
 const MiContexto = useOutletContext();
 return (<CrearContacto setOpening={MiContexto.modalState}/>
//code continues
```

MainLayout class:

```
 import Navbar from "./Navbar"
    import Topbar from "./Topbar"
    import React, {useReducer} from "react";
    import { Outlet, useOutletContext } from "react-router-dom";
    
    export const MainContexto = React.createContext({modalState:false});
    
    const initialState=false;
    
    const estadosPosiblesModal = (state, action) =>{
      switch(action){
        case false:
          return false;
        case true:
          return true;
        default: 
          return state;
      }
    }
    const MainLayout = ()=> {
    const [EstadoModal, dispatch] = useReducer(estadosPosiblesModal,initialState);
    
      return (
        <MainContexto.Provider value={{modalState:EstadoModal,modalDispatch:dispatch}}>
          <div className="mainlayout">
            <Navbar/>
            <main className="mainlayout_topPlusContent">
              <Topbar className="TopBar" prueba={EstadoModal}/>
              <Outlet context={{modalState:EstadoModal,modalDispatch:dispatch}}/>
            </main>
          </div>
        </MainContexto.Provider>
      );
        
    };
    
      export default MainLayout;
```

I had to use simultaneously a custom context and the Router outlet context as my context wasn't going through the outlet.

Topbar contains:

```
  const micontext = useContext(MainContexto);
...
        <Button variant="contained" onClick={()=>micontext.modalDispatch(true)}>
```

Comment: Component props are read-only, so you cannot do `setOpening=false`. Only the parent component can change `setOpening`. Read https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only

Comment: so how could I change "open" from another component?

Comment: See my answer below on how to do that. Although I am not sure if that's causing re-renders, props are read-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you call `setOpen(setOpening)` on the component level `CrearContacto` which is causing the infinite re-renderings on that component. You can imagine this cycle: state update (`setOpen(setOpening)`) > re-rendering > call state update again > ...

And another problem is you cannot set `setOpening=false` directly, it needs to be set with a state setter from the parent component.

```
export default function CrearContacto({setOpening}) {
      
      const [open, setOpen] = useState(setOpening);
      //setOpen(setOpening); //remove this part

      useEffect(() => {
         setOpen(setOpening)
      },[setOpening])
    
      const handleClose = () =>{setOpen(false)}; //set `open` state internally instead
    
      return (
        <div>
          <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
        </div>)
}
```

---

If you want to update the parent component's state, you should pass the state setter and state value to your child component which is `CrearContacto` too

I'd assume that you have this state on the parent component

```
const [opening, setOpening] = useState(false);
```

*Note that `setOpening` is following the naming convention of the state setter, so I'd prefer to do it this way instead*

You can try to modify your component like below

```
export default function CrearContacto({setOpening, opening}) {
      
      const [open, setOpen] = useState(opening);
      //setOpen(setOpening); //remove this part

      useEffect(() => {
         setOpen(opening)
      },[opening])
    
    
      const handleClose = () =>{setOpening(false)};
    
      return (
        <div>
          <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
        </div>)
}
```

If you only use `open` state for `Dialog`, you can remove that state declaration too

```
export default function CrearContacto({setOpening, opening}) {
    
      const handleClose = () =>{setOpening(false)};
    
      return (
        <div>
          <Dialog open={opening} onClose={handleClose}>
        </div>)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your example. Actually the "true" comming from the button is just a trigger that sends always true so the dialog popup shows. I was testing how to show the dialog using a button because I had to use a context since the button is in a element not related, the button clicks, changes context state, and it shows like this in the parent:   <CrearContacto setOpening={MyContext.modalState}/> which is true when the button is pressed. I don't see how to approach this in a better way.

Comment: Hmm if you can share the parent component, we may have some ideas about how to construct your states @Germán

Comment: I added relative code to the issue. Please not I just started using context and I'm not familiar with it so I might be using it wrong. Please, if you could, lend me a hand on this.

Comment: I believe I just made it work by changing handle close to the following:   const handleClose = () =>{MiContexto.modalDispatch(false)};

Comment: yeahh it is! I was just about to tell it. I'd suggest you also should modify `setOpening` name to `opening`. That's hard to understand it's a value instead of a state setter though @Germán

Answer (score 0):

To expand my comment:

- From inside (or a child) component, you can change the `open` value by using the state, so call the `setOpen` function.
- From a parent component you can change the value of `open` by changing the prop `setOpening` (rename this prop as it sounds like it's a function), so you would have:

```
export default function CrearContacto({setOpening}) {
    
      const [open, setOpen] = useState(setOpening);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        console.log(setOpening);
        setOpen(setOpening);
      }, [setOpening]); 
    
      const handleClose = () =>{setOpen(false)};
    
      return (
        <div>
          <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
```